# How do I access MysqlServer on my PC with a PHP script from a remote hosted server?

Tags: php, mysql, server, mysql-workbench, connexion

I installed MysqlServer and Mysql Workbench on my PC. The server is running well (green color).
Now I have a shared hosted server and I would from this server via a PHP script to fetch data from the database on my PC. For the moment there is not database or any data because I just want to first make the connexion between the two servers. I tried a lot of times to make a connexion without any success until now.

→ Using Workbench via Option file,  I put in bind-address, the IP provided by my hosted server. (= the remote server that wants to access to my MysqlServer on my PC).

→ I also enabled SSL connexions as my hosted website is on SSL.

→ Then, in users and privileges, I put % on the root user so that root can connect to the MysqlServer on my PC from another host (not only localhost).

→ I've allowed incoming rules for port 3306 on my Windows firewall.

→ The basic code I am using is a basic PDO PHP database connexion where $host is the public IP of my pc, $port is 3306, $root is root and the password is the one I created during the installation of MysqlServer.

The basic code I am using is :

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";port=".$port, $root, $root_password);
}
    catch (Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

→ The error I have is : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to MySQL server on « Public Ip address of my PC ».

Does someone already have this kind of problem ? Can you see any thing strange that could helped me ?
Any answers, suggestions, remarks or questions are greatly welcomed.

Comment: bind address is for the public address of the mysql server, not the remote server. you need to expose the mysql server on internet before you can continue

Comment: Why not put all your data on the webserver? Your website won't run properly if your local IP address changes, or the local computer is shut off

Comment: @ Lelio Faieta : I change the bind-address with my public IP of MysqlServer on my PC, then restart the service but it shows the same error.
@Nico Haase : Because I want the data to be decentralized and used by the user's PC. If my PC is shut off, then I will design an offline layout for the website. If I use the public IP, then I think it would not changed.

Answer (score -1):

There are two types to connect to a database-

```
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=dbname','root','');
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

OR

```
$connect = new mysqli("localhost","root","","dbname");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why? Which of the two types resolves the given error message?

Comment: Also, I doubt that `localhost` would properly connect from a remote webserver to my local database server

Comment: I think the way my code is written is OK (you can try a connexion without a database name after what I read in StackOverflow). But the problem is really that it seems that there is no server on my PC but it's running well on my PC... The connexion is somehow not made, don't understand why.